# How to install adobe air in AVD

Tags: adobe-air

i developped an android application using adobe flash professional and i need to try it with a virtual device, i failed to install adobe air under AVD and Genymotion, for Genymotion some services are limited in case of free version, can someone describe haw to fix my problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

35 minutes and solution found by myself

1. Execute the emulator
2. Start the console (Windows XP), Run -> type cmd, and move to the platform-tools folder of SDKdirectory.
3. Paste the APK files (adobeair.apk and myapp.apk) in the 'platform-tools' folder.
4. Then type the following command. adb install adobeair. apk adb install myapp.apk And finally your application works fine.
   [download adobe air](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0PighVz7eAGLUl4MFdROVAtMVE/view?usp=sharing)